# Error: yarn start - error Command "start" not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to learn React and I am using a private repo to start with it.

I run `yarn start` in the directory of the repo but I get the error message:

```
yarn run v1.13.0
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have both node and yarn installed.

For node:

```
v10.15.0
node is /usr/local/bin/node
```

For yarn:

```
1.13.0
yarn is /usr/local/bin/yarn
```

I tried to reinstall both node and yarn but I get the same error message. moreover I tried to remove the yarn chance via `yarn cache clean` but nothing seems to work.

The `package.json` contains the following:

```
{
  "name": "02-Manipulating-Strings",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "ssaunier",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.7.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "jest": "^21.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "(eslint lib || true) && jest"
  }
}
```

The directory is organised in the following way:

[image: project directory]

Comment: Can you show us the `package.json` file and more specifically the "scripts" section?

Comment: Just added it, thanks.

Comment: You don't have any script named start in package.json

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no `start` command inside the scripts of the `package.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "some command to be run", // you need to add this line
  "test": "(eslint lib || true) && jest"
}
```

Maybe you want to run the `test` command instead - `npm test` / `yarn test`?

Comment: That is what I was thinking too but I have 2 remarks. 1) I opened the solution file of the private repo and the soultion's `package.json` matches mine (plus, yesterday eberything was working) 2) How can I run the JS files in the folder `lib` if i do not run `yarn start`? I tried with `npm run` but I get: `Lifecycle scripts included in 02-Manipulating-Strings:
  test
    (eslint lib || true) && jest`

Comment: If I try to run: `node lib/01_dash_insertion.js` nothing happen. So I tried to install `npm install --save-dev webpack`but still I cannot run any js file.

Comment: "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"

Comment: So, `yarn` behavior is to look at the `scripts` "section" in case it can't match one of its sub-commands?

Answer (score 10):

Just run

```
yarn add react-scripts
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Still have the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

Solved it thanks to the insight of the user: Tsvetan Ganev.

I was trying to run a command that it is not in my scripts. Specifically, `yarn start` is not in the `scripts` part of the file `package.json`.
To solve the issue I added the following line in `scripts`

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
```

Comment: please mark Tsvetan Ganev. reply as an answer if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to run first `npm install` and then `npm run` or first `yarn` and then `yarn start`

Comment: I tried with yarn and yarn start, I am still getting the following error. yarn run v1.22.10
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: Try adding: "start": "react-scripts start" in your "scripts" inside package.json

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error message "start" command not found. My issue got resolved by following the below mentioned steps.

-open the folder in which you want to create the app using terminal then type these commands:

1. **npm uninstall -g create-react-app**
2. **npx create-react-app FolderName**

(This will automatically install the latest create-react-app version)

-Then run the command **yarn start** and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. I figured the best way is this.

1. npm i -g create-react-app
2. create-react-app my-react-app //or whatever you want your project to be
3. cd my-react-app
4. yarn start

Answer (score 4):

Well, I was getting this error cause I was dumb Not going inside the main project folder.so it actually not able to find .json file too

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This should be on top.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue start command not found.
I followed below instruction to recreate react app

```
. Go to your parent folder in cmd
. Type yarn add create-react-app
. And yarn create-react-app FolderName
```

After installing yarn start will work.

[image: After Installing react folder]

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to package.json worked for me

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using create-react-app and encountered this error, chances are you did not install create-react-app successfully.

Try removing globally installed create-create-app as explained below.

[Template not provided using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

check your package.json that has "start" scripts. 
if you just have dependency list, make sure you have the following on the package.jons

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@theia/cli": "next"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "yarn run clean && yarn build && yarn run download:plugins",
    "clean": "theia clean",
    "build": "theia build --mode development",
    "start": "theia start --plugins=local-dir:plugins",
    "download:plugins": "theia download:plugins"
  },
  "theiaPluginsDir": "plugins",
  "theiaPlugins": {
    "vscode-builtin-css": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/css-1.39.1-prel.vsix",
    "vscode-builtin-html": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/html-1.39.1-prel.vsix",
    "vscode-builtin-javascript": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/javascript-1.39.1-prel.vsix",
    "vscode-builtin-json": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/json-1.39.1-prel.vsix",
    "vscode-builtin-markdown": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/markdown-1.39.1-prel.vsix",
    "vscode-builtin-npm": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/npm-1.39.1-prel.vsix",
    "vscode-builtin-scss": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/scss-1.39.1-prel.vsix",
    "vscode-builtin-typescript": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/typescript-1.39.1-prel.vsix",
    "vscode-builtin-typescript-language-features": "https://github.com/theia-ide/vscode-builtin-extensions/releases/download/v1.39.1-prel/typescript-language-features-1.39.1-prel.vsix"
  }
}
```

otherwise run this on the folder where package.json is

error Command "start" not found.

```
yarn run theia start /home --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

theia should start on port 8080 minimally.

Answer (score 1):

**Nov 2020**

This might happen when you clone a git repo created with an older version of create-react-app or event with another setup.
First install react-scripts as

> yarn add react-scripts

Or

> npm install react-scripts

Then if having problem with react-scripts, refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115884/error-when-updating-create-react-app-to-4-0-with-typescript-template).

Answer (score 1):

If you get `error Command "start" not found.` after creating new project using create-react-app you most probably would have created the app using `npm`.

To do it correctly delete the directory of the project and recreate the project using yarn with the following command

```
 yarn create react-app my-app
```

After that yarn start works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

i got the same issue. it cusses you have installed packages in wrong directory.

in cmd terminal:-(D:\PROJECT)=> my cmd file path shows

```
D:\PROJECTS\npx create-react-app app-react
```

(when you enter this command it will create new file named app-react . then you have to go into the app-react file . use this command to go to the that file "cd app-react" then enter. you will see cmd path     )

```
D:\PROJECTS\cd app-react
D:\PROJECTS\app-react\
```

then install other yarn packges

```
D:\PROJECTS\app-react\yarn add @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react@^11 @emotion/styled@^11 framer-motion@^4

D:\PROJECTS\app-react\yarn add react-icons

D:\PROJECTS\app-react\yarn add react-router-dom
```

then yarn start

```
D:\PROJECTS\app-react\yarn start
```

if it is won't open check yarn package installed using this command

```
D:\PROJECTS\app-react\yarn -version
1.22.10
```

for install yarn

```
npm install --global yarn
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

just run following commands:

1. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
2. npx create-react-app FolderName

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while I have `"start"` script in my `package.json`. Eventually, I figured out that I had not saved the `package.json`, so I got this error. Obviously, after saving the `package.json` the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when file "package.json" will gets deleted or changed. Please check your
"package.json" file.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound silly, but I was having this same problem and all I did was close the program (vscode), and reopen it. I made sure it was inside the correct project folder (web) and did the process again. It worked. In my case it was just a lack of attention.

I hope your problem is as simple as mine.

Hug!

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem whit this:
Since create-react-app 3.3.0 it's not longer recommended to use a global installation of CRA.

However, after following the recommended way, uninstalling CRA globally and using npm,I ran into the following problem for my new React project:

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.

It seems like CRA wasn't properly uninstalled. I had to do the following:

After uninstalling it with npm uninstall -g create-react-app, check whether you still have it "installed" with which create-react-app on your command line. If it returns something (e.g. /usr/local/bin/create-react-app), then do a rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app to delete manually.

Afterward, I was able to use npx create-react-app my-app with the latest version of CRA where I would have the default template for the src/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can try

```
npm install
```

then

You can also try to run first npm install and then npm run or first yarn and then yarn start

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issues with the following command. Try this command, hope you will get rid of the problems.

```
npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face this error but in my case I think, I have done all the above steps but the error still remaining the last thing I did in my main `node_module/.bin/` folder I saw there are two dependencies one is `create-react-app` it fine but another one is `creat-app-react` so I deleted this dependency and also remove from my package.json file.

So now yarn start is working perfectly.

Comment: This is not related to this case. The OP had a problem with running a command that did not exist in the package json because it was not intended to.

Answer (score 0):

just run command

```
corepack disable
```

if you ran the following command before

```
corepack enable
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was outside the project. So I type `cd myProject` and than `yarn run`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: [/vue-components|views/],
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
},
```

put this in webpack.config.js in module object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

one of the reasons behind this is watch if you are in the right directory type cd your_file_name then type npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just run

```
npm install --global yarn
```

Comment: this error happens when you're running `yarn start` in a wrong directory instead of the root directory where package.json is. if they didn't have yarn installed then they would've gotten a different error like yarn is not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
 "scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "jest",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"  },
```

I found that when I added this into the scripts section package.json dependency;  it worked! This way, you'll get the https://localhost:3000 instead of using the 8080 port.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and just solved it! Super easy, I hope it helps you:

The problem: "node_modules" was duplicated. You may have accidentally downloaded a duplicated "node_modules" folder when calling yar originally.

Go to "User/#yourname/node_modules" and delete the folder.

Answer (score -1):

just start the app via debug option
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnCQs.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: Please make the differce to the exsting answer more obvious. You seem to just say thanks for https://stackoverflow.com/a/73004724/7733418

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).