# Error: command "start" not found. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am learning React and while implementing my first react app, it shows me this error:

```
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

when I run:

```
yarn start
```

I have installed `create-react-app` globally on my machine.

I also tried to run `npm start` but it shows the **same error**, while searching on internet, I came to know that **npm version 5.0** above may not work properly, and that is why I tried `yarn start` but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `yarn run start`?

Comment: it is still displaying same error with "yarn run start"

Comment: You should NOT install `create-react-app` globally if you are have node verison `5.2+`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538) and [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: Can you add your package.json code?

Comment: @AjeetShah do i always have to install react, whenever i want to create new app ?

Comment: @soulLess here is package.json      {
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
}

Comment: You don't have a `start` command in your package.json, hence the error.

Comment: @code_ghost  To start a new React project, each time you have to do `npx create-react-app my-app --use-yarn` or "--use-npm". "do i always have to install react": What do you mean? "React" is a UI library, yes it will be automatically get installed locally in each project you start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: yarn start - error Command "start" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393192/error-yarn-start-error-command-start-not-found)

Comment: How did you create your react project? "start" command should already be there if you used `create-react-app`.

Comment: @AjeetShah First i installed ```create-react-app``` globally, then i used ```create-react-app project-name``` where whole lots of file got download, then used command ```yarn start``` and shows error.

Comment: @AjeetShah sir, thank you ```npx create-react-app my-app --use-yarn or "--use-npm" ``` worked.