# Error when updating create-react-app to 4.0 with typescript template

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I want to update `react-scripts` to the next version (`4.0.0`) so I can use the fast refresh feature using this guide [here](https://gist.github.com/iansu/282dbe3d722bd7231fa3224c0f403fa1). But when restarting the server, the script doesn't work because of the error below:

```sh
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-scripts start
E:\Github\Web\so-rank\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:210
        appTsConfig.compilerOptions[option] = suggested;
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot add property noFallthroughCasesInSwitch, object is not extensible
    at verifyTypeScriptSetup (E:\Github\Web\so-rank\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:210:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Github\Web\so-rank\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:31:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I applied:

```
rm -rf yarn.lock
rm -rf tsconfig.json
```

Then I reinstalled with the command `yarn`.

Last, `yarn start`.

This way I created the new default file `tsconfig.json` and the file `yarn.lock`.

Comment: I did this but then every time I stop the server it wont restart unless I delete the tsconfig.json file

Comment: ^ fixed by removing all of my dependencies and then re adding them.

Answer (score 61):

This can be fixed by enabling `noFallthroughCasesInSwitch` option in your `tsconfig.json`. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9429#issuecomment-674994709) for more info.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

For anyone curious, the above solution does not fix the bug. It just skips running the buggy code below which will assign the suggested value to the typescript compiler option if not provided. The `tsconfig.json` generated from `react-scripts` by default doesn't have `noFallthroughCasesInSwitch` option. Adding that option removes the need to run the code.

```js
// Some options when not present in the tsconfig.json will be assigned
// a suggested value which crashes the program
if (suggested != null) {
  if (parsedCompilerOptions[option] === undefined) {
    appTsConfig.compilerOptions[option] = suggested; // error here
    ...
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If the script crashes with other options and you have the same stacktrace as the one in my question, you should check if the following compiler options are missing in your `tsconfig.json`

[These](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/ed958938f642007645dd5ac3466db36202f8754e/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js#L116-L160) are the suggested values for Typescript compiler option when not specified in the `tsconfig.json`

```js
const compilerOptions = {
  // These are suggested values and will be set when not present in the
  // tsconfig.json
  target: {
    parsedValue: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5,
    suggested: 'es5',
  },
  lib: { suggested: ['dom', 'dom.iterable', 'esnext'] },
  allowJs: { suggested: true },
  skipLibCheck: { suggested: true },
  esModuleInterop: { suggested: true },
  allowSyntheticDefaultImports: { suggested: true },
  strict: { suggested: true },
  forceConsistentCasingInFileNames: { suggested: true },
  noFallthroughCasesInSwitch: { suggested: true },
  module: {
    parsedValue: ts.ModuleKind.ESNext,
    value: 'esnext',
    reason: 'for import() and import/export',
  },
  moduleResolution: {
    parsedValue: ts.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
    value: 'node',
    reason: 'to match webpack resolution',
  },
  resolveJsonModule: { value: true, reason: 'to match webpack loader' },
  isolatedModules: { value: true, reason: 'implementation limitation' },
  noEmit: { value: true },
  jsx: {
    parsedValue: ts.JsxEmit.React,
    suggested: 'react',
  },
  paths: { value: undefined, reason: 'aliased imports are not supported' },
};
```

You need to explicitly add those options to your `tsconfig.json` so the script can skip the buggy branch and avoid crashing.

Comment: I will wait with upgrading until they fix this. Don't want to bloat my tsconfig with all this!

Comment: I added `"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,` to my `tsconfig.json` but the error still shows up? How can I ensure that `react-script start` really uses my `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I wasn't able to find the problem in my setup, so I had to re-setup my project with `create-react-app my-app --template typescript`. Now everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue when I tried to start to use typescript in my react project, what has solved the issue it's using the next packages with these specific versions in my `package.json`

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"typescript": "^4.1.2",
```

And this `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```